# Flutter Web: Overflow issue in bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Code: Basically I have a simple app with three images aligned. I have 1 column and two rows. First row has two images and second row has 1 image aligned. Its the structure of the app. It just aligns perfectly when run below code in device but the moment I run on WEB there is this overflow. I try resizing the browser window only then it begins to become pretty again. Is there a workaround for Flutter Web please on how should I do the alignments here? Below code is inside body and inside Scaffold. I am attaching pics from device where there is no issue and from Flutter web where there is overflow issue.

```
return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/image1.png'),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: FlatButton(

            child: Image.asset('images/image1.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Image.asset('images/image1.png'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

**Error:**

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
>   ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
>   following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed
>   by 1238 pixels on the bottom.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:   Column
>   file:///C:/Users/1025632/Documents/GitHub/flutter-course/diceylips/lib/main.dart:43:12
>
> The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical. The
>   edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the
>   rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually
>   caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex. Consider
>   applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the
>   children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead
>   of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an error
>   condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
>   seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space,
>   consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the
>   flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a
>   ListView. The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#1ad1e
>   relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING:   creator: Column ← DicePage ←
>   _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
>       CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
>       _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#cb60e ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ←
>       PhysicalModel ← ⋯   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 56.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)   constraints:
>   BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=1280.0, 0.0<=h<=554.0)   size: Size(1280.0,
>   554.0)

direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: center
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down

Image with no issue in device
[Image with overflow issue in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qpno.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the column with a sized box or container with defined height and width

```
SizedBox(
height:200,
width:200,
child: your column goes here,
)
```

Comment: tried this and this helped to some extent only. the entire content is now squeezed to left and the app in web is all empty on the right. I might need to further check alignments properties to bring the content to center..

Comment: Further added sizedbox inside center and possibly the closest to what I wanted. Hope there was a better way though. For now marking this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Add below code inside Container

```
Container(

         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
....
....
)
```

This is the generic way to define full width and height to your Container

Comment: i tried wrapping in container and added the code proposed. its just the same issue. Bottom overflowed by 1268px

Answer (score 0):

If you don't try to fit your widget in screen and scroll is an option for you, you can use listview or a similar widget.

```
ListView(
     children: <Widget>[
              Column(
```

Otherwise, wrapping Container with MediaQuery.of(context).size.width and MediaQuery.of(context).size.height will work but there is just one catch here, if you use an appbar this height should be "MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height"